# Show that the orbits of the induced action of H on X all have the same size.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> If G is a finite group which acts transitively on X (a set), and if H is a normal subgroup of G, show that the orbits of the induced action of H on X all have the same size.

Now I'm not sure what induce here means but i guess that it means that how H now works on X. If this is true, can I just say that H is also transitive because G is transitive and thus there is only one orbit, or am I missing something here?

Comment: You cannot just say that $H$ is transitive because it is not always true! $H$ could be trivial for example.  Do you know about primitive and imprimitive groups? You can show that the orbits of $H$ form a system of blocks of imprimitivity for $G$ and hence they all have the same size.

Comment: If you don't know about primitivity, you can use the fact that for any $x,y\in X$, $x=y^g$ for some $g\in G$. Given that $g^{-1}Hg=H$, if the stabiliser in $H$ of $y$ is $S$ you can show the stabiliser of $x$ is $g^{-1}Sg$. In particular stabilisers have the same size so by the orbit-stabiliser theorem the orbits have the same size. (I've left this as a comment because of how many details I've skipped)